# Unit testing for .net function without classes

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, mocking

I am a .Net developer and need to write a unit test. I have done some online courses for unit testing. But got stuck when it came to real situation.

I need to write a Unit test for a business layers function which gets Customer data from database. Logic to get the data is in Stored procedure inside a database. But i do not need to check the database connection. I will need unit test the function in isolation.

I have seen Moc can be used to imitate classes for Unit testing. In this application Classes are not used. So i am a bit confused on how i can write test cases for this scenario.

The function accepts CustomerId as Input and gives back CustomerName, CustomerCity etc

```
public IEnumerable<GetCustomer_Result> GetCustomer(int CustomerId)
{
return repository.GetCustomerDetails(CustomerId)
}
```

GetCustomer_Result Had properties like CustomerId, CustomerName, CustomerCity

Please let me know how I can write unit test for the above function

Comment: `GetCustomer()` doesn't really sounds like a "business layer function"

Comment: You need to "fake" `repository.GetCustomerDetails` method. For faking you need create abstraction of repository (interface with methods of same signature). But without classes you cannot pass "fake" repository to the business-layer function. So in your case you need to redesign your business layer.

Comment: What is the edition of Visual Studio that you use?

Comment: "In this application Classes are not used." What?  Functions cannot exist without classes in c#